# apacheant mail task and STARTTLS

Tags: java, ant, automation, jakarta-mail

I am trying to send an email around to my team every time someone runs apacheant to update our live server, I am trying to send the email via GMAIL, however when I run, ant upload_live -d I get the following error,

> ```
> BUILD FAILED /Users/simon/Documents/websites/apacheant/build.xml:116: Problem while
> ```
>
> sending mime mail:
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.email.MimeMailer.send(MimeMailer.java:241)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.email.EmailTask.execute(EmailTask.java:577)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>           at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:809)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:217)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
>           at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109) Caused
>   by: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a
>   STARTTLS command first. dp8sm20701038wib.3
>
> ```
>     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1388)
>     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:959)
>     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:583)
>     at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:169)
>     at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.email.MimeMailer.send(MimeMailer.java:239)
>     ... 17 more
> ```

My target definition looks like this,

```
<mail enableStartTLS="true" ssl="no" mailhost="smtp.gmail.com" mailport="587" user="apache.ant.alert@gmail.com" password="*********" subject="${project} Pushed Live">
        <from address="apache.ant.alert@gmail.com"/>
        <replyto address="apache.ant.alert@gmail.com"/>
        <to address="simon@"/>
        <cc address="andrew@" />
        <message>${project} has successfully been transferred via FTP.</message>
    </mail>
    <echo>Mail Sent</echo>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sorted that with the following,

```
<mail enableStartTLS="true" ssl="true" mailhost="smtp.gmail.com" mailport="465" user="apache.ant.alert@gmail.com" password="******" subject="${project} Pushed Live">
        <from address="apache.ant.alert@gmail.com"/>
        <replyto address="apache.ant.alert@gmail.com"/>
        <to address="simon@"/>
        <cc address="andrew@" />
        <message>${project} has successfully been transferred via FTP.</message>
    </mail>
```